Why can if statement works using an object (like Map) with ".has()" and no working with ".includes"?
That's my code to explain my idea better (I'm a non english speaker):
The ".includes()" method doesn't work in this case
const sentence = "hello world hello boy";

let words = sentence.split(" ");

const quantWords = new Map();

for (let word of words) {  
    if (quantWords.includes(word)) {
        quantWords.set(word, + 1);
    } else {
        quantWords.set(word, 1);
    }
}
console.log(quantWords);

Otherwise, using ".has()", it works
const sentence = "hello world hello boy";

let words = sentence.split(" ");

const quantWords = new Map();

for (let word of words) {  
    if (quantWords.has(word)) {
        quantWords.set(word, + 1);
    } else {
        quantWords.set(word, 1);
    }
}
console.log(quantWords);


quantWords.set(word, + 1); really? what happens? btw, the property depends on the object/function. Map has has, strings/arrays have includes.

Misleading description, It's not that the includes method doesn't work. It's that there is no includes method at all! quantWords.includes is not a function

I just had a question about the use of methods in an if statement. Like, why doesn't includes works to check if a value is contained in a Map, but has does? Shouldn't they works the same way for a Map?

Map does not have an includes method

includes is a method name that suggests a linear search, like is the case in an Array or string. But for Map and Set, the keys are accessed in constant (amortised) time, and that is what the name has suggests. It is a quite useful distinction. This is a choice made by the ECMAScript designers (tc39 committee), so just go with it.

It would help people understand your question if you would explain why you think that you should be able to use a method called .includes() on a Map instance and what you think it should do.

I thought has and includes were basically the same thing, so I wondered why includes couldn't be used with a Map.

Thanks for your answers, guys. Now I understand the difference with both very well

The ".includes()" method doesn't work in this case
.includes is available on array objects (searches if the array has the value).
Otherwise, using ".has()", it works
.has is available on Map objects (searches if the Map contains Key).
Your object is of type 'Map'
const quantWords = new Map();


includes is available for strings, too.

Thank you very much ✌️
